# Making a Session service available to my SessionsController in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is probably a matter of me not handling dependency injection proper, but I'm trying to make a 'Session' service available to my SessionsController. Here's my SessionsController:

```
angular.module('App.controllers').controller('SessionsController', ['$scope', '$location', '$cookieStore', 'Session', function($scope, $location, $cookieStore, Session) {

  $scope.foo = function() {
    console.log("clicked foo..");
  }

  $scope.session = Session.userSession;


  $scope.create = function() {

    if ( Session.signedOut ) { 
      $scope.session.$save()
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $cookieStore.put('_app_user', data);
      }); 
    }   

  }; 

  $scope.destroy = function() {
    $scope.session.$destroy();
  };  


}]);
```

Here's the actual Session service definition:

```
angular.module('App.services').service('Session',[ '$cookieStore', 'UserSession', 'UserRegistration', function($cookieStore, UserSession, UserRegistration) {
  this.currentUser = $cookieStore.get('_app_user');
  this.signedIn = !!$cookieStore.get('_app_user');
  this.signedOut = !this.signedIn;
  this.userSession = new UserSession( { email:"foo@bar.com", password:"example", remember_me:true } );
  //this.userRegistration = new UserRegistration( { email:"foo-" + Math.floor((Math.random()*10000)+1) + "@bar.com", password:"example", password_confirmation:"example" } );

  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (current, next) {
    if (this.signedOut && next !== '/login') {
     console.log("relocating user..");
        //$location('/login');
    }});

}]);
```

And here's how I strung it together:

```
angular.module('App.resources', ['ngResource']);
angular.module('App.services', ['ngResource']);
angular.module('App.directives', []);
angular.module('App.filters', []);
angular.module('App.controllers', ['ngCookies', 'Session']);

var App = angular.module("App", ['App.resources', 'App.services', 'App.directives', 'App.filters', 'App.controllers', 'ui.compat', '$strap.directives', 'templates']);
```

Clearly missing something to string everything together as Firebug is complaining that there is no module named: Session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebug is right, you have no module named session. You have a service named Session in the App.services module.

Just remove the Session module injection, and you are good to go.

```
angular.module('App.controllers', ['ngCookies']);
```

Comment: Interesting. Now when I do that, I get `Error: Unknown provider: UserSessionProvider`. I guess that's a separate problem, though.

Comment: In this case, this means you are trying to use the UserSession service, but you have not created it yet. I suppose you will experience the same with UserRegistration too. I would provide you a link to the documentation but it seems to be down now. But yo need the creating angular services and injecting angular services (or understanding dependency injection) sections.